repaint does not update without mouse movement or keyboard action
I noticed that when I try to force a repaint within a function, it only works if I move the mouse or hit a key of the keyboard.
Is there a way to repaint even without any mouse/keyboard event?
I am using python 3.12.6 on archlinux
$ pip list
Package            Version
------------------ -------
pip                24.2
PySide6            6.8.0.2
PySide6_Addons     6.8.0.2
PySide6_Essentials 6.8.0.2
shiboken6          6.8.0.2


Here is a minimal example:
import sys
import random
import time
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click me!")
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.magic)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def magic(self):
        print("Change button")
        self.button.setText("I am sleeping")
        self.button.repaint()
        print("Label changed, sleep")
        time.sleep(2)
        self.button.setText("Click me!")
        print("Should be back to normal")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.resize(200, 200)
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())

When you run this python script you see a button. When you click on it the behavior change whether you are moving the mouse or not.
If you move the mouse after clicking you will see 'I am sleeping' while if you do not move the mouse, the text will stay 'Click me!'.
I was expecting to see 'I am sleeping' even without any mouse movement. How to solve this?
Thanks for your input

Things like time.sleep() (similarly to while loops) are blocking, preventing the event loop to process anything, including repainting or processing mouse actions. This happens for almost any UI based toolkit and should always be avoided in main UI calls. If you just want to restore the "Click me!" text 2 seconds after clicking, then use QTimer functions: eg. QTimer.singleShot(2000, lambda: self.button.setText('Click me!')). Then do some research about event based programming, UI toolkits, and dealing with their delayed calls, as there are thousands of resources on the matter.

Thanks @musicamante, the time.sleep() was a place holder for a function that is taking time to execute. Using your answer I changed my code to:
    def longfunction(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        self.button.setText("Click me!")
        print("Should be back to normal")

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def magic(self):
        print("Change button")
        self.button.setText("I am sleeping")
        self.button.repaint()
        print("Label changed, sleep")
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.longfunction)


But out of curiosity, could you explain me why in the first minimal example, when you don't move the mouse the button text is not repainted but if you move the mouse it is repainted?
Thanks

The point is that anything that may be blocking (whether it's time.sleep() or a long running computation) should normally be avoided, possibly using separate threads (if it deals with I/O) or by periodically invoking QApplication.processEvents() (for CPU bound computations). Using QTimer.singleShot to run the "long function" after calling repaint is fundamentally pointless. There can be many reasons for which the button is repainted after the first mouse movement (depending on the OS and the complexity of both the UI and what's being called in the meantime), but you shouldn't rely on that.
